# PDO Condition: created date is today

Tags: php, date, drupal-7, mysqli

Im trying to set a 'date=today' condition on my query. Dates in the DB are stored as '1351504197'.

this is my attempt:

```
->condition('cord.created',REQUEST_TIME - 3600, '<=')
```

and this is the full query:

```
  $query = db_select('commerce_order', 'cord')->extend('TableSort');
  $query->join('commerce_line_item', 'li', 'cord.order_id = li.order_id');
  $query->join('commerce_product', 'item', 'item.sku = li.line_item_label');
  $query->fields('cord', array('order_id'))
        ->fields('li', array('quantity'))
        ->fields('item', array('title', 'sku'))
        ->groupBy('title')
        ->condition('cord.status', 'pending', '=')
        ->condition('cord.created',REQUEST_TIME - 3600, '<=')
        ->orderByHeader($header); 

  $query->addExpression("GROUP_CONCAT(li.order_id separator ', ')", 'order_id');         
  $query->addExpression('SUM(quantity)', 'quantity');
```

but the results returned are not correct, of course.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: What library are you using to wrap PDO?

Comment: im not exactly sure what you mean, I'm developing in drupal 7 (mysqli/php)

Comment: Then why do you have `PDO` tagged in your question? Also you should then put `Durpal-7` `mysqli` tags because those libararies could have an impact on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a unix timestamp. if you're using native MySQL date/time fields, you'll have to convert between them, using [from_unixtime()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) or [unix_timestamp()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

the fix was:

```
  $today = getdate();
  $start_time = mktime(0, 0, 0,$today['mon'],($today['mday'] - 1), $today['year']);
  $end_time = time();

  ->condition('cord.created', array($start_time, $end_time), 'BETWEEN')
```